# Control the volume on TextToSpeech function call

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

**Hi guys**

I've been looking around but cannot seem to find a suitable answer to integrate into my function. I am basically using the following code currently:

```
    private void sayHello(String timeString) {

    textToSpeech.speak(timeString,
    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
    null);
}
```

This code works fine but it's **too loud** and it can only be **controlled by the volume of the device itself**. I want to be able to **adjust/hardcode/be able to use spinner** to control the volume of the TTS but cannot seem to do so accordingly.
Is this functionality available for this library? Is it achievable? 

I've also tried to implement the following into my code:

```
KEY_PARAM_VOLUME
```

However, I cannot see any examples of this being used and it's showing up with the error to create a function. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int androidAPILevel = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void start() {
        if (androidAPILevel < 21) {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, "0.5"); // change the 0.5 to any value from 0-1 (1 is default)
            tts.speak("This is a volume test.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
        } else { // android API level is 21 or higher...
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putFloat(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, 0.5f); // change the 0.5f to any value from 0f-1f (1f is default)
            tts.speak("This is a volume test.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bunz, works as expected. However, the main volume of the phone still impacts the TTS. For example: if I set the volume to max manually in my code and mute the volume on the phone, I won't hear anything (as you'd expect). Is there a way I can program the function to ignore the volume of the phone?

Comment: I think you could technically ignore volume button presses while your app is in the foreground, but you can't simply ignore the system volume setting.  Either way, it doesn't sound like a good idea because you're not responsible for whether the phone is muted or not.  One thing you could do is calculate the volume setting in your code based on the volume of the device.  Could ask a new question though as I am not actually sure.